# IE and compatability mode, why does it mess with browser identification scripts?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a script below that uses `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` because `get_browser()` is not active on the server and the administrator of said server (hotgator) will not activate it for me.

That being said, I am running IE 8 in Windows XP (VM machine testbed) when I run IE 8 in compatability mode IE shows up in the script below as IE 7, instead of IE 8.  Why?

```
<?php
//This is a script that will identify the OS and browser you are using.
// This also has a fix in where Chrome shows up as Chrome, 
// and not show up as Safari by accident. 



//Booleans to set OS and Browser to False.
$os = false;
$browser = false;
//Booleans for Web Browser & OS Functions.
$info = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$xp = 'Windows NT 5.1';
$vista = 'Windows NT 6.0';
$win7 = 'Windows NT 6.1';
$ubuntu = 'Ubuntu';
$ie106 = 'ie106';
$ie10 = 'ie10';
$ie9 = 'ie9';
$ie8 = 'MSIE 8.0;';
$ie7b = 'MSIE 7.0b;';
$ie7 = 'MSIE 7.0;';
$chrome = '/Chrome/';
$safari = '/Safari/';
$firefox = '/Firefox/';


//Operating Systems
if (stristr($info, "Windows NT 5.1")) {echo 'You are using a Windows XP Operating System ';}
if (stristr($info, "Windows NT 6.0")) {echo 'You are using a Windows Vista Operating System ';}
if (stristr($info, "Windows NT 6.1")) {echo 'You are using a Windows 7 Operating System ';}
if (stristr($info, "Ubuntu")) {echo 'You are using an Ubuntu Operating System ';}
if (stristr($info, "Mac OS")) {echo 'You are using a Macintosh Operating System ';}


//Web Browsers
if (stristr($info, "Chrome") !== FALSE) {stristr($info,"Safari");
        $chrome = 'Chrome';
            echo 'with a Chrome Web Browser ';}
elseif (stristr($info, "Safari")) {echo 'with a Safari Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "Firefox")) {echo 'with a Firefox Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 7.0;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 7.0 Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 7.0b;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 7.0b Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 8.0;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 8.0 Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 9.0;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 7.0 Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 10.0;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 7.0 Web Browser ';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 10.6;")) {echo 'with a Internet Explorer 7.0 Web Browser ';}



//If OS or Browser not found in list.
if ($ubuntu || $xp || $vista || $win7)
$os = true;

if($firefox || $chrome || $safari || $ie9 || $ie8)
$browser = true;

if(!$browser || !$os){

echo'<strong>';
echo '<br />' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . '<br />Please copy and paste the text above and send it to your web administrator. It will explain everything he/she needs to do.';}

?>
```

Comment: Because running Internet Explorer 8 (and 9, as it happens) in compatibility-mode is intended to be the same as running Internet Explorer 7?

Comment: Because IE7 emulation mode causes the browser to emulate IE7 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in compatibility mode IE8 drops back to the IE7 rendering to be compatible with sites designed for the older browser specifically. It therefore needs to identify itself to the webserver as such so that sites return the correct content if they provide differing content for different versions of web browser.

Compatibility mode is [explained on the MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx).

Comment: And if only it rendered the page the same as IE7 did this might actually be useful.

Comment: @DampeS8N thats right it only emulates IE7 rather than actually using the original IE7 rendering engine from what I could see in the linked article in my answer.

Comment: [Emulates with differences that matter. Which means they added a new thing to code to rather than taking away a new thing to code to.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx)

Comment: @DampeS8N Agreed - you are preaching to the choir here.

Comment: So is there a way to tell if a browser is in comparability mode, and to show it's real browser behind it in php or is this a java thing?

Comment: @MattRidge not unless the browser some how broadcasts this. If it is not in the user agent string then I don't see how you can find out with PHP. Perhaps there is some JS variable set that you can access, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: @Treffynnon Is there is possibility of it working in html5 or am I just barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: @MattRidge I don't see how the HTML version of the page will help you here, sorry.

Comment: @Treffynnon: The browser does broadcast its true rendering engine, via the TRIDENT token in the UA string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe "compatability mode" completely emulates IE7, that why it calls so. Why — ask MS.